# Float object is not subscriptable - Python-3

Tags: python

```
 ....
goodness = {}
n = G.nodes()
    iter = 0
    while iter < 100:
        df = 0
        dg = 0
        for node in n:
            in = G.in_edges(node, data='weight')
            g = 0
            for edge in in:
                g += fairness[edge[0]]*edge[2]["weight"]
            try:
                dg += abs(g/len(in) - goodness[node])
                goodness[node] = g/len(in)
            except:
                pass
.....
```

I am getting the TypeError: 'float' object is not subscriptable for the line "g += fairness[edge[0]]*edge[2]["weight"]",
I have no idea what is the meaning of this error as the code is not mine, I am just trying to understand the idea.

Comment: `a[i]` gives you `ith` element from the sequence `a`. One of the things from that line which you are trying to access using `[]` is not a sequence but a float. Try printing the values to see.

Comment: Thank you for your time. @lllrnr101
I solved the problem.